# make a snapshoot object of the current status of a static class

Tags: c#, static

I have a static class in my system keeping track of the frequency of measurements, the number of samples currently read, what sensors are on an which are off and all those nice details.

Now I make a measurement and want to create a report in the report I want to save all the information stored in the static class. something like this :

```
public static class Details{
    public static int samplesRead { get; set;}
    public static int frequency { get; set;}
    public static List<devices> devices { get; set;}
}

public class Patient{...} // name, surname , blabla

public class ResultsSet {
    public DateTime date;
    public Patient patient;
    public *DetailsObject* details;
}

public void main {
   patient p = new patient(...);
   ... make the measurements ...

   var results = new ResultSet();
   results.patient = p;
   results.DateTime = DateTime.Now();
   results.details = **here the magic ** Details.ToObject();

   results.Serialize(myFilePath);
}
```

How can one acomplish that conversion to a single defined object?

Comment: If you want to save and restore it, make it a non-static class and serialise/deserialise it using JSON or XML.

Comment: But I want the class to be static because it guarantees only one copy of each stuff is there and is super useful acceding from multiple parts of the system and for my multi thread problems. I mean... I defined it static for my reasons. Please don't judge them and let's find a way to do that.

Comment: You'll probably have to write some custom code then. Most serializers only work on non-static properties.

Comment: problem creating properties in the resultSet and then manually copying from the Details class is that keeping everything is a hassle. If someone adds a property in the Details then someone else have to notice and add it also to the details.. definitely not what you want to do ...

Comment: If you really have to use a static class for whatever reason (you can ensure a single instance better by using the singleton-pattern, but anyway) that you have to set every property of `results.details` appropriately, e.g.`result.details.sampelsRead = Details.sampelsRead`.

Comment: Does your *Details Object* class repeat same fields as static class *Details* have?

Comment: @BagdanGilevich my Details Object class does not exists. I wanted somehow C# to be smart enough to create it from my static class on the fly so if I add an item to the static class it appears in the object from there on

Comment: @MongZhu My main concern is not the serialization is the capability of making an snapshot of the static class in an object. For instance to be able to check what changed along the time on its values. No necessarily to serialize it at all. Just make an object.

Comment: ok I got distracted by the serialization issue. I posted an answer using a DTO (Data Transfer Object) or using reflection

Comment: Could be worth looking at the `Memento` design pattern for this - https://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is the capability of making an snapshot of the static class in an object. [...] Just make an object.

So what you could do is to create a DTO that has the same properties as your static class:

```
public class DetailsSnapshot 
{
    public int samplesRead { get; set; }
    public int frequency { get; set; }
    public List<device> devices { get; set; }
}
```

Not you can map and return such an object at any given time:

```
public static class Details{
    public static int samplesRead { get; set;} 
    public static int frequency { get; set; }
    public static List<device> devices { get; set; } 

    public static DetailsSnapshot MakeSnapShot()
    {
        return new DetailsSnapshot
        {
            samplesRead = samplesRead,
            frequency = frequency,
            devices = devices.ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

You can have then such an snap-shot-object in your results:

```
public class ResultsSet
{
    public DateTime date;
    public Patient patient;
    public DetailsSnapshot detailsSnapShot;
}
```

and make the snap shot (**here the magic**) the following way:

```
results.detailsSnapShot = Details.MakeSnapShot();
```

EDIT:

There is also a way using reflection. With this approach you would scan your `Details` class for the properties and extract the values. You could return a `Dictionary` which basically maps the names of the properties to the values:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> MakeSnapShotReflection()
{
    PropertyInfo [] allPorperties = typeof(Details).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    Dictionary<string, object> valuemapping = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < allPorperties.Length; i++)
    {
        valuemapping.Add(allPorperties[i].Name, allPorperties[i].GetValue(null));
    }

    return valuemapping;
}
```

This way would allow you to extend the `Details` class with further properties without worrying about extending anything else.

Or the short version:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> MakeSnapShotReflection()
{
    PropertyInfo[] allPorperties = typeof(Details).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    return allPorperties.ToDictionary(key => key.Name, value => value.GetValue(null));
}
```

With this approach you could still use intellisens to access the correct values:

Test Data:

```
public static class Details
{
    public static int samplesRead { get; set;} = 100;
    public static int frequency { get; set; } = 2700;
    public static List<device> devices { get; set; } = new List<device>() 
    { 
        new device { Name = "sensor1" }, 
        new device { Name = "sensor 2" } 
    };
}

public class device 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test Code to access values:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> details = Details.MakeSnapShotReflection();

    Console.WriteLine(details[nameof(Details.frequency)]);
    Console.WriteLine(details[nameof(Details.samplesRead)]);

    foreach (var element in details[nameof(Details.devices)] as IEnumerable<device>)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> 2700
>   100
>   sensor1
>   sensor 2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save and restore it, make it a non-static class and serialise/deserialise it using JSON or XML. You can then go JsonConvert.SerialiseObject and JsonConvert.Deserialise object. Nice and simple.

If you want to ensure only one instance, make the class a singleton.

```
public class Details
{
    private static readonly Details _instance = new Details();

    static Details() 
    {
    }

    private Details()
    {
    }

    public Details Intance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public int samplesRead { get; set;}
    public int frequency { get; set;}
    public List<devices> devices { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access it's properties this way:

```
Details.Instance.samplesRead
```

If the class has to be static, you can use reflection to serialise it:

```
public static string SerializeStaticProperties(Type type)
{
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    var data = new List<Property>();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        data.Add(new Property
        {
            Name = property.Name,
            Type = property.PropertyType,
            Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(property.GetValue(null))
        });
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}

public static void DeserializeStaticProperties(Type type, string json)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Property>>(json);

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(item.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(null, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item.Value, item.Type));
        }
    }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: uf .. the Details class is coded by someone else and is already used in around 40K lines of code but .. your design look super neat.

Comment: if no one solves the actual problem I asked, I will eventually mark this answer as solution

Comment: @javirs it is called a [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) , very usefull

Comment: @javirs Added another option to this answer.